# theoremstyle is not applying I think

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, newtheorem

I would like to use different theorem styles for my definitions and remarks. but somehow the command `\theoremstyle{definiton}` does not change anything at all at the moment: here's the code would love some help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[satz]{Korrolar}
\theoremstyle{definiton}
\newtheorem{rem}[satz]{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem{defn}[satz]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\begin{satz}
    test one two three
\end{satz}
\begin{defn}
    test one two three
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

for some reason the satz and defn have the same style...

Comment: You've spelt definition wrong, you have `\theoremstyle{definiton}` missing an i, it should be `\theoremstyle{definition}`

Comment: `\theoremstyle{definiton}` results in the following warning: "Unknown theoremstyle `defintion`". You probably wanted to use `\theoremstyle{definition}` instead (Notice the previously missing "i" right after the "t".

Answer (score 1):

This is because you wrote `\theoremstyle{definiton}` instead of `\theoremstyle{definition}` (note the additional `i`)

Comment: thank you hate when something so easy is the solution and I sit here for 20 min trying to figure it out.